# NSURL - Set modify path

Tags: ios, nsurl

I need to use a `NSURL` object to reach different ressources on the same host.

Here is what I do:

```
#define MY_HOST @"my.server.eu"
NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithScheme:@"http" host:MY_HOST path:@"/"];
```

Now I need to deal with

- http://my.server.eu/path1
- http://my.server.eu/path2
- http://my.server.eu/path3

How can I modify the path of my `NSURL` object ?
Why can't we simply do `url.path = @"path1"` ?

Comment: What about generating string within a loop, and converting it into NSURL ?

Comment: This url is a public member of a class that I use in several different location. You are saying I have to recreate the NSURL each time I need it ?

Comment: Yes, something like this NSString *str=[NSString stringwithFormat:@"%@%d",url,counter], and then convert it into url as NSURL *finalURL = [NSURL URLWithString:str];

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How can I modify the path of my `NSURL` object ?
>
> Why can't we simply do `url.path = @"path1"` ?

Because `NSURL` is an immutable object, and you can't change its properties afterwards. `NSMutableURL` does not exist, but is on the wish list of many.

In order to achieve what you're after, you're going to have to make 3 separate `NSURL` objects I'm afraid. To do so, you can convenience the paths within an array:

```
NSString *host = @"http://my.server.eu/";
NSArray *paths = @[@"path1", @"path2", @"path3"];

NSURL *path1 = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", host, path[0]]];
NSURL *path2 = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", host, path[1]]];
NSURL *path3 = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", host, path[2]]];
```

Comment: Wow ! Ok I think I'm not even going to use this object finally :) (actually I wanted to use it only for taking advantage of his url building functions) Thank you for the unmutable explanation.

Comment: Don't get me wrong, the use of `NSURL` can be mighty handy, but it's not as flexible as most would hope.

Comment: I hope it's handy, I'll surely use it later :)

Answer (score 1):

You should make the base URL as you're doing and then build the others relative to it using `+[NSURL URLWithString:relativeToURL:]`.

Comment: This would bring the maintainability but I still have to do `[[NSURL alloc] initWithString: my_path relativeToURL: url].absoluteString` each time I need to get the new url string, don't I ?

Comment: If you need a string from it, yes, you have to ask it for a string.